# Vim FoldColumn color different on Debian / Ubuntu

Tags: vim, vimrc

I sync my [.vimrc file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denten/.dotfiles/master/.vimrc) between two machines, one running Debian testing and the other Ubuntu. On Debian everything works fine.

On Ubuntu, the fold column is gray instead of black, even though black is specified:

`213: hi FoldColumn ctermbg=Black ctermfg=Black`

If I comment out line 213, the fold column turns black, but then foldmarkers default to white (the whole point is to hide them black on black). If i just do:

`213: hi FoldColumn ctermfg=Black`

The FoldColumn is gray again. I do not find plugin conflicts with `grep -r "FoldColumn" .vim/`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are other colors affected as well? And are you using the same terminal on both systems?

Comment: No other colors are affected. I'll check the terminals in a few, that seems like a promising direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` which means that when you're in TTY, the background will be black as well as the foreground (=text).
If you want to set color for gui/xorg, use `guibg` and `guifg`, like so:

```
hi FoldColumn  guibg=black guifg=LightGray ctermbg=black ctermfg=LightGray
```

Hope this fixes your problem.